# Are the following statements true or false

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

Question:

Are the following statements true or false:

1. A system with more variables than equations must have a solution.
2. If the coefficient matrix of a homogeneous system with 4 equations and 7 unknowns has rank $ 2$ then there are 2 basic solutions.
3. Consider homogenous system $ Ax = 0$ where $ \ A$ is a $ 4 \times 5$ matrix. If the system has a non trivial solution then RREF of $ \ A$ must have a row of zeros.

My attempt:

$1$ is false.

Consider $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0& 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ \end{array}\right]$$

$2$ is false

If we have $ \ n = 7$ variables and rank $ 2$ then we have $ \ 7 -2 = 5$ basic solutions one for every parameter.

$3$ is false I think
I can't come up with a counter example.

Is my answer and approach to the first two correct? Could someone help me with 3 please.

Comment: 3) What is the simplest RREF of a $4\times 5$ matrix you can think of for a matrix that avoids having a row of zeroes?  Does that matrix have a nontrivial solution?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The counter-example for $1)$ has one variable, but at least one equation. Choose $$x+y+z=1$$ $$x+y+z=2$$ as a counter-example.